# How do I change the string representation of a Python class?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, printing

In Java, I can override the `toString()` method of my class. Then Java's print function prints the string representation of the object defined by its `toString()`. Is there a Python equivalent to Java's `toString()`?

For example, I have a PlayCard class. I have an instance c of PlayCard. Now:

```
>>> print(c)
<__main__.Card object at 0x01FD5D30>
```

But what I want is something like:

```
>>> print(c)
A♣
```

How do I customize the string representation of my class instances?

I'm using Python 3.x

Comment: This is about class instances, not classes. Should we update the title?

Answer (score 400, accepted):

The closest equivalent to Java's `toString` is to implement `__str__` for your class. Put this in your class definition:

```
def __str__(self):
     return "foo"
```

You may also want to implement `__repr__` to aid in debugging.

See here for more information:

- [Special Method Names - Basic Customization](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customization)

Comment: Wow, that's a pretty old version of the docs ;) `s/release\/2.5.2\//`

Comment: The OP said that he is using python 3. Sub-classing object is not required.

Comment: Dude __repr__ resolve

Answer (score 48):

This is not as easy as it seems, some core library functions don't work when only **str** is overwritten (checked with Python 2.7), see this thread for examples
[How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)
Also, try this

```
import json

class A(unicode):
    def __str__(self):
        return 'a'
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'a'
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'a'

a = A()
json.dumps(a)
```

produces

```
'""'
```

and not

```
'"a"'
```

as would be expected.

**EDIT**: answering mchicago's comment:

unicode does not have any attributes -- it is an immutable string, the value of which is hidden and not available from high-level Python code. The `json` module uses `re` for generating the string representation which seems to have access to this internal attribute. Here's a simple example to justify this:

`b = A('b')
print b`

produces

`'a'`

while

`json.dumps({'b': b})`

produces

`{"b": "b"}`

so you see that the internal representation is used by some native libraries, probably for performance reasons.

See also this for more details: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/python-string-objects-implementation/

Comment: I dont think any output of 'a' would be expected. Json serialisation dosn't look at functions but at attributes and the class A dosn't contain any attributes, just three functions. Json dumps treats the object as a dictionary, and will convert all keys to strs.

Comment: I'm not quite sure why you're mixing "to string" and `json.dumps` which are two completely different things.