# Class Method; returning given input

Tags: python

I have the code:

```
class Triangle(Coordinate):
    def __init__(self,xcoord,ycoord,color):
        self.color = color
        super().__init__(xcoord,ycoord)
```

(inheriting from class Coordinate)
And whenever I call it, for example

```
t1 = Triangle(Coordinate(1,1), Coordinate(2,1), Red)
```

It only returns the coordinates, how do it make it return the color as well?

Comment: How does it return the coordinates?

Comment: def __str__(self):
        return 'Coordinate('+str(self.x)+','+str(self.y)+')', I know I have to override it but idk how

Comment: Just add in `str(self.color)` to that string (with plus signs, of course)

Comment: Copy that function into your `Triangle` class before you modify it.  That will override the `Coordinate` class.

Comment: I can't change anything in the Parent Class though

Comment: `Triangle(...)` does not return the coordinates, it does return object of type `Triangle`. Do you mean string representation of that object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the string representation of a Python class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912852/how-do-i-change-the-string-representation-of-a-python-class)

Answer (score 0):

The answer has been posted in the comments but I think you misunderstood him, so I am going to elaborate a bit more.

Your class Triangle inherits functions from a parents class of some sort. Even though you didn't write a `def __str__(self):` in Triangle, it can still be used because it is defined in your parent class, and Triangle inherits functions from the parent class

If you don't want to use any of the parent class' functions, you can **redefine** it in Triangle. When you call that function on a Triangle Python will prefer to use the `def __str__(self):` in Triangle before referencing the parent class.

In short, you need to write a new `def __str__(self):` similar to the one in your parent class, but add another portion in the output that accounts for the color. I hope this helps Charmaine. Good luck!

Comment: That makes sense thank you! But it's still giving me the wrong result for some reason

Comment: Make sure you spelled the function exactly as it appears in the parent function then edit it to include the color.