# super __str__ isnt getting called

Tags: python, oop, scikit-learn

I'm inheriting `from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier`, and I'm trying to print my new estimator:

```
class my_rf(RandomForestClassifier):
    def __str__(self):
        return "foo_" + RandomForestClassifier.__str__(self)
```

gives `foo_my_rf()`

I also tried:

```
class my_rf(RandomForestClassifier):
    def __str__(self):
        return "foo_" + super(RandomForestClassifier, self).__str__()
```

with the same result. expected is something pretty like sklearn default behaviour:

```
>>> a = RandomForestClassifier()
>>> print a
RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
        max_depth=None, max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None,
        min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
        min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10, n_jobs=1,
        oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
        warm_start=False)
>>>
```

This is also the result when I use `print a.__str__()`.

What am I missing? 
Thanks.

related to [How do I change the string representation of a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912852/how-do-i-change-the-string-representation-of-a-python-class)

Comment: Evidently the parent class `__str__` implementation is the name of the class. You are calling it correctly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - oops, edited the question to make clear what am I looking for.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the `__repr__` instead?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - yes, same result. I must be missing something with objects vs. classes, in python I always do :)

Comment: Not necessarily - does a base `RandomForestClassifier` give the result you're looking for when `str`/`repr`d? If not, you'll have to write it all yourself.

Comment: What does `str` produce if yo *don't* override `__str__` and what is your expected output to achieve? And what's the significance of the added code with the massive amount of parameters?

Comment: @5gon12eder - if I don't override, it's just `my_rf()`. If I use the `__str__` of the base `RandomForestClassifier` I get the nice representation with all the parameters, which is what I want

Comment: I see, I didn't realize the code you were showing was supposed to be *output*. I have edited your post to make this clearer.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `super(my_rf, self).__str__`? By specifying `super(RandomForestClassifier, self)`, you are effectively **skipping** `RandomForestClassifier`'s implementation of `__str__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `RandomForestClassifier` both `__repr__` and `__str__` lookup the name of the class of the instance they are called from (`self`). You should directly reference the name of the superclass.

**Update** This is how you can get your desired output, though I don't get, why would you want something like that. There is a reason why `RandomForestClassifier`'s `__str__` and `__repr__` return the actual name of a class. That way you can `eval` to restore the object. Anyway,

```
In [1]: from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
In [2]: class my_rf(RandomForestClassifier):
    def __str__(self):
        superclass_name = RandomForestClassifier.__name__
        return "foo_" + superclass_name + "(" + RandomForestClassifier.__str__(self).split("(", 1)[1]

In [3]: forest = my_rf()
In [4]: print forest
foo_RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=True, class_weight=None, criterion='gini', max_depth=None,
   max_features='auto', max_leaf_nodes=None, min_samples_leaf=1,
   min_samples_split=2, min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, n_estimators=10,
   n_jobs=1, oob_score=False, random_state=None, verbose=0,
   warm_start=False)
```

**Update 2** You get no parameters when you override `__init__`, because in the superclass `__str__` and `__repr__` are implemented to scan the list of arguments passed to `__init__`. You can clearly see it by running this code:

```
In [5]: class my_rf(RandomForestClassifier):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        RandomForestClassifier.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def __str__(self):
        superclass_name = RandomForestClassifier.__name__
        return "foo_" + superclass_name + "(" + RandomForestClassifier.__str__(self).split("(", 1)[1]
In [6]: forest = my_rf()
In [7]: print forest
...
RuntimeError: scikit-learn estimators should always specify their parameters in the signature of their __init__ (no varargs). <class '__main__.my_rf'> with constructor (<self>, *args, **kwargs) doesn't  follow this convention.
```

Comment: While this is not what the OP has asked for, it might be what they actually want.

Comment: oops, edited the question to make clear what am I looking for.

Comment: @EliKorvigo, sorry - this gives `foo_RandomForestClassifier()` and NOT the correct representation with all the estimator's parameter. Perhaps this is something specific to `sklearn`...

Comment: @ihadanny It clearly does give you the correct representation with all the estimator's parameters as shown in my example.

Comment: @EliKorvigo - you are right. In my case it does not work because I did another thing, I overided init as well : `    def __init__(self):
        RandomForestClassifier.__init__(self, n_estimators=25, n_jobs=12, oob_score=False, max_features='sqrt', min_samples_leaf=1)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110229/discussion-between-ihadanny-and-eli-korvigo).