# python print class text passed to a variable

Tags: python, string, printing

I want to write to a text file the function text as it is passed to a variable:

```
myvariable = myClass(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg_n)

f = open("mytextfile.txt", "w")
f.write("here is my paremeters:"+ str(myvariable))
f.close()
```

in my printout text file, I get:

```
"here is my parameters:<somefunction.myClass instance at 0x7d54a5101b48>"
```

the desired output will be:

```
"here is my parameters: myClass(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg_n)"
```

I should use the `myvariable` because the arguments change from time to time, so I can't hardcode the function text as it is.

Comment: how did you get that and not the result of run de function? is it your function defined?

Comment: @Tzomas sorry you r right, it is a class, not a function. anyway, it doens't affect my question...

Comment: Hard to help without seeing `myClass` definition

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the string representation of a Python class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912852/how-do-i-change-the-string-representation-of-a-python-class)

Comment: Define a `__str__` or `__repr__` method for `myClass`

Comment: what is myClass, does it has any function or constructor or anything?

Comment: @cricket_007 here is the exact file I am using https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom/blob/master/minisom.py class MiniSom

Comment: @Hackaholic here is my class that i use https://github.com/JustGlowing/minisom/blob/master/minisom.py

Comment: Then extend that class and/or implement your own `str()` implementation on it

Comment: @cricket_007 could you please suggest an answer with your solution? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you commented with a third-party library and this isn't your own class...

Not pretty, but it works.

```
def string_it(c):
    return """myClass({}, {}, {}, {}, {})""".format(
        c.arg1, c.arg2, c.arg3, c.arg4, c.argN
    )

f.write("here are my parameters: {}\n".format(string_it(myvariable)))
```

Or you can try to implement it on that variable.

(haven't tried myself, but it is just a function re-mapping)

```
myvariable.__str__ = lambda s: """myClass({}, {}, {}, {}, {})""".format(
        myvariable.arg1, myvariable.arg2, myvariable.arg3, myvariable.arg4, myvariable.argN
    )
```

And then `str(myvariable)` might work