# Django How to see the session data insted of the object reference

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-sessions

Im trying to start using session in django, Im trying to see the data in my session but im just getting the object reference not the data

console:

<cart.cart.Cart object at 0x7f6994753160>

views.py

```
def cart_view(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    print(cart)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'cart/cart_page.html')
    else:
        return redirect('account:login')
```

cart.py

```
class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):

        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get('cart')
        if not cart :
            cart = self.session['cart'] = {}  #cria a sessão cart
        self.product = cart
```

Comment: you can override the `__str__` and `__repr__` methods of any class you want in python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the string representation of a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912852/how-do-i-change-the-string-representation-of-a-python-class)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can override the `__str__` method on anyclass to control how it is converted to a string... you can also override the `__repr__` method if you need to as well

```
class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):

        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get('cart')
        if not cart :
            cart = self.session['cart'] = {}  #cria a sessão cart
        self.product = cart

   def __str__(self):
       return f"<CartObject {self.product}>"

...
print(cart)
```

Answer (score 3):

`print(request.session.items())`

Answer (score 1):

You can define new method like **get_product**- for your Cart class to get your class attribute

For example

```
class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):

        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get('cart')
        if not cart :
            cart = self.session['cart'] = {}  #cria a sessão cart
        self.product = cart

    def get_product(self):
        return self.product
```

And then you can use get_product method after create new object from Cart class:

```
def cart_view(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    print(cart.get_product()) # this line where you call your new method 
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'cart/cart_page.html')
    else:
        return redirect('account:login')
```

or you can just override **str** function:

```
class Cart:
    def __init__(self, request):

        self.session = request.session
        cart = self.session.get('cart')
        if not cart :
            cart = self.session['cart'] = {}  #cria a sessão cart
        self.product = cart

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.product}"
```

now you can just print out your cart object, it will print your product

```
def cart_view(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    print(cart)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return render(request, 'cart/cart_page.html')
    else:
        return redirect('account:login')
```

Comment: the get_product did'nt work

Comment: @kaynanfeliperodriguesvieira  they mean you would then do `print(cart.get_product())` but you could also just do `print(cart.product)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).